# stepping out of 'for' loop while debugging in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm debugging using android studio,currently my break point is inside "for" loop and execution keep  jumping back and forth in the loop(as expected )but i want to step out of this loop as it is a too long to go till the end.

Comment: remove your breakpoints inside loop and continue.

Comment: Is there no other way to step over .